# Setup Branches with GIT

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I have various things I've written, and rewritten a couple times, without keeping track, and git seems the perfect solution to merge my disjointed code. However, the tutorials had me running around in circles for 3 hours now, and it shouldn't be this difficult.

Once I get to conflicts, I think I know how to merge them, but I can't seem to get branches setup.

This will create the situation I want to resolve:

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
mkdir a b c d merge
echo "foo" >> a/foo
echo "foo" >> b/foo
echo "foo" >> c/foo
echo "foo" >> d/foo
echo "bar" >> b/foo
echo "bar" >> c/foo
echo "bar" >> d/foo
echo "totally" >> c/foo
echo "totally" >> d/foo
echo "beyond" >> d/foo
cd a 
git init ; git branch -m a ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../b
git init ; git branch -m b ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../c
git init ; git branch -m c ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../d
git init ; git branch -m d ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../merge/
git init ; git branch -m merge ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
```

Now, what I want to do is pull a into merge, check it;
then pull b into merge, resolve conflict (diff);
then pull c... Repeating until "merge" contains everything, corrected.

But everything I try does something weird, like, it puts branches into sub-folders, not actually merging them. And every tutorial I have read anywhere just talks about how to checkout from github... I'm not using git hub, it works fine locally, I want to just use it locally.

Help?

Comment: I've been using git to pull code and edit, occasionally submitting stuff back for a long time. I have some serious doubts that this book will explain my question, I will look at it and get back to you if I find a section that addresses this issue, that is, not pulling from a remote, and merging several previously untracked forks.

Comment: Nope, that's useless, it's written for windows users, it's written to clone something first, it's exactly what I mentioned all the documentation reads like. It's just how to clone a remote, and how to init a project. It does not address the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are running `git init` on each individual folder. This creates a *new* repository. At the end of your scripts above, you have five *different* repositories, rather than one repository with multiple *branches*.

This essentially looks like:

```
|      |      |      |      |
A      B      C      D      E
```

When you want:

```
 main ----------------------------------------------
       \ -- A -- /  \          /   \             /
                     \-- B -- /     \           /
                                     \ -- C -- /
```

In the above, the `main` branch contains all of the code from the various feature branches after a merge.

To achieve this, you only need to run `git init` once, in the main project folder. `.git` applies to all subfolders by default, so when you attempt to `git add` any files from subfolders, they will automatically become part of the singular repository, and get picked up by `git diff`.

After merging (with `git merge`), your `main` branch will contain the commits from `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Comment: Confusing. so just go ahead and add them as subfolders? No line brakes, hitting enter in a comment only posts it, sorry it's on one line. '''git add ../b ``` to add the folder (not sub-folder, but we are now making them "git" sub folders, even though they are not in the same directory). And then git will identify that ../b/file1 is to be merged with /merge/file1? How will it know which are to be merged? There are no "subfolders" in the directories, they all have different versions of the same files, in other directories, unless git knows ../b from within /merge is the same? I'll test it.

Comment: Didn't work for me, still doing something wrong, git remote add a ../a/ doesn't work unless it's init in a, and adding doesn't work, it will not accept it when it's not already in the directory: git add ../a fatal: ../a: '../a' is outside repository at '/usr/home/rob/tmp/merge'

Answer (score 0):

This might be slightly crazy, but I think this is what you're going for?

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
mkdir a b c d merge
echo "foo" >> a/foo
echo "foo" >> b/foo
echo "foo" >> c/foo
echo "foo" >> d/foo
echo "bar" >> b/foo
echo "bar" >> c/foo
echo "bar" >> d/foo
echo "totally" >> c/foo
echo "totally" >> d/foo
echo "beyond" >> d/foo
cd a 
git init ; git branch -m a ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../b
git init ; git branch -m b ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../c
git init ; git branch -m c ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../d
git init ; git branch -m d ; git add . ; git commit -m initial
cd ../merge/
git init ; git branch -m merge ; git commit -m initial --allow-empty

git remote add a ../a
git remote add b ../b
git remote add c ../c
git remote add d ../d

git fetch --all

git merge a/a --allow-unrelated-histories --no-edit
git merge b/b --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge c/c --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge d/d --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Note that the first change I made to your sample commands was adding `--allow-empty` to the initial commit for the `merge/merge` branch since there were no files on that branch.

Image of resulting commit-graph for the `merge/merge` branch.

[image: git-commit-graph]

If every git-merge is done with the option `-Xtheirs`, this is the resulting `foo` file on branch `merge/merge`:

```
foo
bar
totally
beyond
```

Comment: That looks promising! Yes, I get it's a bit crazy (not typical use) but yes, I think that will help! I'll try it later when I get time. Thank you!